# NodeJS AWS Lambda ListObject returning empty array

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS. I am creating a Scheduled lambda function using NodeJS. There I need to get all the objects in a folder and iterate through each, to check the last modified date and I want to delete old objects. But I am getting empty array in ListObject's Response Contents.

```
var s3 = new aws.S3();
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

var params = {
    Bucket: 'bucket_name',
    Delimiter: '/',
    Prefix: 'folder_name',
    MaxKeys:100000
};
s3.listObjects(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else
  {     
    var folderLength = data.Contents.length;
    data.Contents.forEach(function(metadata) {
      console.log('Key: ' + metadata.Key);
    });

  }
});
callback(null, 'Finished');
};
```

But in the response i am getting `Contents: []`. Can anyone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Are you running the lambda and s3 on the same region?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting an empty array? To me, it seems you are terminating the lambda before any result comes back. The callback function call should be withing the listObject result function.

Comment: The pseudo-folders in S3 should have a hidden trailing slash. Please verify whether adding a trailing slash to the folder name fixes your issue, and I'll provide more explanation in an answer.  Try `Prefix: 'folder_name/',`.

Comment: That's a good point, @jens.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot Prefix: 'folder_name/' was the issue. If u post it as answer i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [`ListObjects()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property) with `Delimiter: '/'`, there are two arrays of interest inside `data`: `Contents` and `CommonPrefixes`.

`Contents` is the list of objects beginning with the `Prefix` value you specified up to but not including the next `Delimiter`, and `CommonPrefixes` is a list of the prefixes common to all the objects with the prefix of `Prefix`, up to and including the next occurrence of `Delimiter` (which is `/` by convention).

S3 doesn't actually have folders -- just objects that share common prefixes, delimited with `/`.

When you create a folder `foo` in the S3 console, an empty object with a key of `foo/` is actually created.  However, if you upload an object with key `foo/bar.html` using the API, the console will -- for convenience -- still display this as a file `bar.html` inside a folder named `foo`, even though in this latter case, no `foo/` object was explicitly created.  Significantly, in neither case is the object actually "in" a meaningful "folder" container.  It's only presented that way.  S3 has no actual folders -- only objects and buckets.

If you want all the objects "in a folder," what you're really saying is that you want the objects sharing a common key prefix.

But when S3 provides a list of all objects sharing the common key prefix "folder_name" *up to the next `/`* (as noted above) then there aren't any.

In your original code, `Contents` is empty, but you would have found that `data.CommonPrefixes` in the response contained a single value, `folder_name/`, because all of the objects whose keys begin with `folder_name` *up to the next `/`* actually share the common prefix `folder_name/`.

There's no point in making two requests with the first one being redundant and unnecessary (and, in fact, doing so will give you incorrect results if more than one folder has a name *beginning with* "folder_name") so when you want a list of objects "in a folder," the correct approach is to set the `Prefix` to `folder_name + '/'`.